# build a query to look for a mapserver feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using openlayers 4.4.0 and I'm trying to build a query to look for a mapserver feature and display the polygon.

I was inspired by this example without success, collecting an error 57 (I do not find where to find the errors of openlayers 4.4).

https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html

How can I correctly build this request please?

I try this code and get error 57

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
// generate a GetFeature request
      var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featureNS: 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs',
        featurePrefix: 'ms',
        featureTypes: ['emprise'],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        filter: ol.format.filter.and(
            //ol.format.filter.like('name', 'Mississippi*'),
            ol.format.filter.equalTo('numope', 'FA11163001') //example numope=='FA11163001'
        )
      });
// then post the request and add the received features to a layer
      fetch('http://10.210.1.32:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/map/fond_mapserver_wfs_ol4.map', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        //map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
        console.log ('featuresrequest',features)
      });
```

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/errors/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `and` filter which requires at least two conditions (as your error suggests). Uncomment the first filter in the `and` function or use only the `equalTo` filter.

```
var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
    featureNS: 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs',
    featurePrefix: 'ms',
    featureTypes: ['emprise'],
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    filter: ol.format.filter.equalTo('numope', 'FA11163001') 
});
```

You can find the error codes at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/errors/ as geocodezip mentioned in their comment.

Comment: Ok I understand but it still does not work. 

I do not know how to configure this query with filter. 

here is a part of the desribefeaturetype. 

<schema targetNamespace="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.1">
<import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
<element name="emprise" type="ms:empriseType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="empriseType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<sequence>

Comment: but I know how to add the filter directly to the url as 
&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>" + listeNumOpe + "</PropertyName><Literal>" + choixNumOpe + "</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>

Comment: but I would like to know how to correctly configure this query with filter

Answer (score 0):

for the moment this works

```
    var listeNumOpe = 'numope';//document.getElementById("listeNumOpe").value;
    var choixNumOpe = 'FA11139401';//document.getElementById("choixNumOpe").value;
    var searchOpeUrl = "http://10.210.1.32:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/map/fond_mapserver_wfs_ol4.map&SERVICE=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=emprise&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>" + listeNumOpe + "</PropertyName><Literal>" + choixNumOpe + "</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>&outputFormat=geojson" 
    ;
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

// then post the request and add the received features to a layer
      fetch(searchOpeUrl).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
        var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json,{ 
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:2154',
            featureProjection:'EPSG:3857' });
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
        });
```

Comment: try to debug the url which is sent to the WFS in the network tab of the dev tools. I guess the featurerequest ist not right compared to the direct url you are sending